# Importing data with non-standard blank columns in R

Tags: r, csv, import, tidyverse, na

I'm trying to import a data set to work with in R (using the tidyverse). Unfortunately, its a government data set which almost always means some odd standards. In this case, where a certain observation doesn't have a value for a given variable, ND has been entered as a text string.

I am reluctant to open it up in Excel and manually track down every ND to replace it with a blank cell (even using find and replace) - because it obviously makes my code less replicable. But not doing so means that, when I import the data using read_csv, some of my variable types don't work properly (e.g. I can't happily make a column a double). Is there a way, in the data import process, to replace all of those ND entries with "standard" NAs?

I've included my code below.

Apologise if this is an obvious question with a simple answer - I'm fairly new to this.

Thanks

```
> #Load libraries
> library(tidyverse)
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
v ggplot2 3.2.1     v purrr   0.3.3
v tibble  2.1.3     v dplyr   0.8.3
v tidyr   1.0.0     v stringr 1.4.0
v readr   1.3.1     v forcats 0.4.0
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

> 
> #Import data
> 
> #From March 2020, REGION_GEOG and REGION_GEOG_CODE fields removed 
> GP.prac.Mar20 <- read_csv(
+   "Data/GPWorkforcePracticeLevel/17. General Practice March 2020 Practice level.csv",
+   col_types = cols(
+     .default = col_double(),
+     PRAC_CODE = col_character(),
+     PRAC_NAME = col_character(),
+     CCG_CODE = col_character(),
+     CCG_NAME = col_character(),
+     PCN_CODE = col_character(),    
+     PCN_NAME = col_character(),
+     STP_CODE = col_character(),
+     STP_NAME = col_character(),
+     REGION_CODE = col_character(),
+     REGION_NAME = col_character(),
+     HEE_REGION_CODE = col_character(),
+     HEE_REGION_NAME = col_character(),
+     CONTRACT = col_character(),
+     GP_SOURCE = col_character(),
+     NURSE_SOURCE = col_character(),
+     DPC_SOURCE = col_character(),
+     ADMIN_SOURCE = col_character()
+   )
+ )


|=================================================================| 100%   11 MB
Warning: 91380 parsing failures.
row                    col expected actual                                                                               file
  9 TOTAL_DPC_HC           a double     ND 'Data/GPWorkforcePracticeLevel/17. General Practice March 2020 Practice level.csv'
  9 TOTAL_DPC_DISPENSER_HC a double     ND 'Data/GPWorkforcePracticeLevel/17. General Practice March 2020 Practice level.csv'
  9 TOTAL_DPC_HCA_HC       a double     ND 'Data/GPWorkforcePracticeLevel/17. General Practice March 2020 Practice level.csv'
  9 TOTAL_DPC_PHLEB_HC     a double     ND 'Data/GPWorkforcePracticeLevel/17. General Practice March 2020 Practice level.csv'
  9 TOTAL_DPC_PHARMA_HC    a double     ND 'Data/GPWorkforcePracticeLevel/17. General Practice March 2020 Practice level.csv'
... ...................... ........ ...... ..................................................................................
See problems(...) for more details.

>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I realised that as long as I can work out what the NA value is, I can specify it when importing using `na =`, so `read_csv("path", na = "ND")`

Answer (score 0):

try reading the files using `data.table's` `fread()` using the proper `na.strings =`  settings

```
library( data.table )

#without na.strings set
data.table::fread( 
"col1, col2
ND, test" )

#    col1 col2
# 1:   ND test

#with na.strings set
data.table::fread( 
  "col1, col2
  ND, test", na.strings = "ND" )

#    col1 col2
# 1:   NA test
```